# Angular: Unit testing if else statement

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write a simple test like:

```
it('should return smaller', function() {
    expect($scope.test).toEqual('smaller');
});

it('should return bigger', function() {
    $scope.x = 15;
    expect($scope.test).toEqual('bigger');
});
```

controller:

```
$scope.x = 4;

if($scope.x > 6) {
    $scope.test = 'bigger';
}else{
    $scope.test = 'smaller';
}
```

First test is correct but the second test fails. Setting $scope.x = 15 in the test doesn't change the situation. 
So how can I test that?

Live: http://plnkr.co/edit/QZf3Vdvj1hbaBd4xBk3p?p=preview

Comment: What function is the logic in the controller wrapped in?  Or is it simply in the constructor function?  If it is in the constructor function for the controller, then, in your test, you need to control when that logic is running (i.e. when the controller is created.

Comment: you should put the testing code which is in your controller in a function and call it at the runtime then call it again after assigning an other value to `$scope.x`